# How to uninstall MiniPort Wan (IP) on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, wan

My father's laptop can't connect to the network printer through WIFI. We were able to narrow the problem. Three MiniPort WAN are dysfunctionnals and are displayed with a warning by Windows.

In ordre to solve this issue I need to be able to uninstall these drivers. There are some explanations available, but they do not work with Windows 8. In order to re install theses drivers, they must disapear from the device manager.

Here is the problematic part, I can't achieve it. [See](https://web.archive.org/web/20200807172058/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/BrentCaskey/archive/2011/06/09/re-installing-wan-miniport-devices.aspx) , deleting the register break down the wifi. I do not have errors when I uninstall these drivers, but they do not disapear from the device manager.

[Another link](https://www.chicagotech.net/VPN/error720b.htm), explains that we must uninstall TCP/IP, before deleting the register key. But you can't uninstall TCP/IP on windows 8 because it is a core component. You can reset the driver easily still.

The only known way (at least to me) to uninstall these drivers is to delete them in Windows/inf, and in system32 (not sure for this one). The author explained that it made the drivers disapear from the device manager, but windows became soon quite unstable.

So do you have any ideas ?

Edit : I'm a software engineer, so I can handle technical explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way around the issue with resetting the ip protocol and not being able to uninstall the wan miniport.

I used this link here, and instead of the bridge I changed the driver to something I didn't have already in my device manager. Some of them still wouldn't allow me to uninstall, but I was able to get it done after trying a couple.

http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/55611-fix-broken-wan-miniports

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. What do you mean by "I changed the driver to something I didn't have already in my device manager"? Can you be more specific than "I was able to get it done after trying a couple."?